# What is the difference between a Data Transfer Object (DTO) and a proxy object?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, dto, proxy-pattern

I just do not see the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to compare apples with oranges but the primary difference will be in their purpose and implementation of business logic.

[Data Transfer Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) is used to carry the data between boundaries e.g. processes. It does not implement business logic and is only used to store, retrieve or serialize the data.

[Proxy Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) is used as an intermediary to access some other object e.g. database connection. It can implement additional business logic.